# Complex Venn Diagramm

Tags: tikz-pgf, venn-diagrams

Further to my question on [Venn diagrams overlapping color filling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188455/venn-diagrams-overlapping-color-filling), I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,fadings,patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]\centering
\pagestyle{empty}
\def\firstcircle{(0,0) circle (2.0cm)}
\def\secondcircle{(360:3.5cm) circle (2.0cm)}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
    \fill[style=shade, top color=white, bottom color=brown!80!black!20][black] \firstcircle;
    \fill[style=shade, top color=white, bottom color=cyan!80!black!20 ][black] \secondcircle;
    \draw \firstcircle node{\textsc{Rules-Based (Passive)}};
    \draw \secondcircle node{\textsc{Bet Against Market Portfolio (Active)}};
     \clip \firstcircle;
  \fill[red][fill opacity=0.6]\secondcircle;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

However, instead of output (bottom picture) I want to achieve a Venn-diagram that includes circles and can handle longer text; similar to this (upper picture in blue and purple): How to achieve this?[image: Double Venn]

Comment: Use `align=center` for the nodes and `\\` to mark the desired line-breaks?

Comment: Adding the ['align=center'] did not alter the figure. Maybe I misplaced the command?:                              `\secondcircle;
        \draw \firstcircle node[align=center]{\textsc{Rules-Based/ (Passive)}};
        \draw \secondcircle node[align=center]{\textsc{Bet Against/ Market Portfolio/ (Active)}};`

Comment: NB reversing the / in \ did not alter either

Comment: Should be `\\\` but the system turned my double backslash into a single. Sorry about that.

Comment: A minor pedantic point — the figure 1.2 above is an [Euler diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_diagram), not a [Venn diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A possible implementation with the new Blend Modes feature from TikZ v. 3.0.0 (see [What are the new features in TikZ/pgf 3.0?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153392/what-are-the-new-features-in-tikz-pgf-3-0)). This allows to avoid using some clip operation:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\def\firstcircle{(0,0) circle (3.0cm)}
\def\secondcircle{(360:3.5cm) circle (3.0cm)}
\begin{tikzpicture}[blend group=screen]
\begin{scope}[fill opacity=0.3,text opacity=1,white,align=center,text width=2.5cm]
    \draw[fill=blue!50!cyan!60!black] \firstcircle 
    node[shift={(-.75,1)},text=blue!50!cyan!60!black]{\textsc{Rules-Based (Passive)}};
    \draw[fill=violet!60!red] \secondcircle 
    node[shift={(.75,1)},text=violet!60!red]{\textsc{Bet Against Market Portfolio (Active)}};
    \node[text=white] at (1.65,0){\textsc{Strategic Beta}};
    \begin{scope}[scale=0.8,transform shape,align=center,white,fill opacity=1]% little circles
    \draw[fill=blue!50!cyan!60!black](-0.5,-1.25)circle(1.45cm) 
     node[text width=2.25cm,text=white] {\textsc{Market-Cap\\ Weighted}};

     \draw[fill=violet!60!red](6,-1.25)circle(1.35cm) 
     node[text width=2.25cm,text=white] {\textsc{Actively\\ Managed}};
    \end{scope}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Well done Claudio! In my document class [https://github.com/suchow/Dissertate], in which I have added the tikz package and its relevant commands, I have no output, though. Trust your code is right (given your shown output) and I will try to manage to get the PDF output!

Comment: @Lingskiwitz: Glad you like it! The point, as said at the beginning, is that `blend group=screen` only works with the newest TikZ version. You can check yours by inserting somewhere in the document `\pgfversion`.

Comment: I use Tikz 3.0; the error-log gives: Tex capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]. (...t={(-.75,1)},text=blue!50!cyan!60!black]{...)

Comment: @Lingskiwitz: Why don't you compile the current document and you include the resultant pdf via `\includegraphics`? Unfortunately, by only seeing the error it is really not possible to give you a correct feedback.

Comment: That is a good suggestion. I also see some alternative solutions on expanding Tikz memory at `http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7953/how-to-expand-texs-main-memory-size-pgfplots-memory-overload`; though it appears they come with backlashes. Thanks again Claudio!

Answer (score 5):

You can also do this sort of diagram in plain [Metapost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107489/what-is-metapost-metafont-and-how-can-i-get-started-using-it), using the built in colour-arithmetic.

[image]
Colours can be thought of as `(r,g,b)` 3-tuples, but you can add, subtract, and scale them as vectors. Plain MP defines

- `red` as `(1,0,0)`
- `green` as `(0,1,0)`
- `blue` as `(0,0,1)`
- and `white` as `(1,1,1)`.

Values `>1` are treated as `1` for the purposes of making colours.
Adding up two colours and subtracting enough `white` to get each component back into the range 0 to 1, usually makes a nice blend of them.

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";
verbatimtex
\let\\=\cr
\font\sc=phvr8r
\def\stack#1{$\vcenter{\halign{\sc{##}\hfil\cr#1\crcr}}$}
etex
beginfig(1);

u = 8mm;

path a[];
a1 = fullcircle scaled 9u shifted (3u,0);
a2 = fullcircle scaled 9u shifted (-3u,0);
a3 = fullcircle scaled 3u shifted (4u,-2u);
a4 = fullcircle scaled 3u shifted (-2u,-2u);
a5 = buildcycle(subpath(-2,2) of a2, a1);
a6 = buildcycle(subpath(-2,2) of a4, a1);

color filler[];
filler1 = .2 red  + .1 blue  + .7 white; 
filler2 = .2 blue + .1 green + .7 white;
filler3 = .6 red + .3 blue;
filler4 = .55 blue + .35 green;
filler5 = filler1+filler2-white;
filler6 = filler1+filler4-white;

for i=1 upto 6: fill a[i] withcolor filler[i]; endfor
for i=1 upto 4: draw a[i] withpen pencircle scaled 0.2 withcolor white; endfor

label(btex \stack{Bet Against\\
              Market Portfolio\\(Active)} etex scaled 1.4, center a1 shifted (+2/3u,2u)) withcolor .5 red + .05 blue;
label(btex \stack{Rules-Based\\(Passive)} etex scaled 1.4, center a2 shifted (-2/3u,2u)) withcolor .1 green + .35 blue + .1 white;
label(btex \stack{Actively\\Managed}      etex, center a3) withcolor white;
label(btex \stack{Market-Cap\\Weighted}   etex, center a4) withcolor white;
label(btex \stack{Strategic\\Beta}        etex, center a5) withcolor white;  

endfig;
end.
```

Comment: This seems a solution for those familiar with Metapost. On a personal note, this is getting too complicated for me to implement.

Answer (score 1):

This might consist of a hint:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={font=\small}]
\begin{scope}
  \node[draw,circle,minimum width=3cm,fill,style=shade, top color=white, bottom color=brown!80!black!20] (one) at (0,0) {};
  \node[below,align=left, text width=1.5cm] at ($(one.north)+(0,-.5)$) {This is a random text};
  \node[draw,circle,minimum width=3cm,fill,style=shade, top color=white, bottom color=green!80!black!20] (two) at (2,0) {};
  \node[below,align=left, text width=1.5cm] at ($(two.north)+(.5,-.5)$) {This is a random text};
  \clip (0,0) circle (1.5cm);
  \fill[red,fill opacity=0.6] (2,0) circle (1.5cm);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

You'll need `calc` tikzlibrary in addition to your `shapes,fadings,patterns`.

Comment: This is a hint, but how to insert the two circles inside circles; and how to get the texts inside? (see my template/ desired output).