# Euler diagram missing a part

Tags: tikz-pgf, euler

Claudio Fiandrino provided a good answer to my question on [Complex Venn Diagramm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208617/complex-venn-diagramm) (actually a Euler diagram). I did alter the code somewhat to make the figure more resemble my previous Venn diagram figure (1.2-see [Complex Venn Diagramm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208617/complex-venn-diagramm)). Though now I've "lost" one of the two smaller "satellites" (the one with SchoolColor-see MWE). How can I get this to appear back?
[image: Eurler diagram]

```
\documentclass{book}
\RequirePackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{SchoolColor}{rgb}{0.6471, 0.1098, 0.1882} % Crimson
\definecolor{forestgreen}{rgb}{0.0, 0.27, 0.13}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}\centering
\pagestyle{empty}
\def\firstcircle{(0,0) circle (3.0cm)}
\def\secondcircle{(360:3.9cm) circle (3.0cm)}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[fill opacity=0.60,text opacity=1,white,align=center,text width=2.5cm]
\draw[style=shade, top color=white, bottom color=cyan!80!black!20 ][black] \firstcircle 
node[shift={(-.55,1.1)},text=black]{\textsc{Rules-Based (Passive)}};
\draw[style=shade, top color=white, bottom color=brown!80!black!20][black] \secondcircle 
node[shift={(.55,1.1)},text=black]{\textsc{Bet Against Market Portfolio (Active)}};
\node[text=black] at (1.95,0){\textsc{Strategic Beta}};
        \clip \firstcircle;
  \fill[red][fill opacity=0.6]\secondcircle;
\begin{scope}[scale=0.8,transform shape,align=center,white,fill opacity=1]
% little circles inside
\draw[style=shade, top color=white, bottom color=forestgreen][black](0.25,-1.45)circle(1.50cm) 
 node[text width=2.25cm,text=white] {\textsc{Market-Cap\\ Weighted}};
 \draw[style=shade, top color=white, bottom color=SchoolColor][black](6,-1.45)circle(1.50cm) 
 node[text width=2.25cm,text=white] {\textsc{Actively\\ Managed}};
\end{scope}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The missing satellite should be the last one to draw, after the last scope; Or it will be clipped.

**Update:** Actually both satellites should be draw lastly, simlifying the codes.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}%{book}
\RequirePackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{SchoolColor}{rgb}{0.6471, 0.1098, 0.1882} % Crimson
\definecolor{forestgreen}{rgb}{0.0, 0.27, 0.13}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
%\begin{figure}
\centering
\pagestyle{empty}
\def\firstcircle{(0,0) circle (3.0cm)}
\def\secondcircle{(360:3.9cm) circle (3.0cm)}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[fill opacity=0.60,text opacity=1, white,align=center,text width=2.5cm]
\draw[style=shade, top color=white, bottom color=cyan!80!black!20 ][black] \firstcircle 
node[shift={(-.55,1.1)},text=black]{\textsc{Rules-Based (Passive)}};
\draw[style=shade, top color=white, bottom color=brown!80!black!20][black] \secondcircle 
node[shift={(.55,1.1)},text=black]{\textsc{Bet Against Market Portfolio (Active)}};
\node[text=black] at (1.95,0){\textsc{Strategic Beta}};
\clip \firstcircle;
\fill[red][fill opacity=0.6]\secondcircle;
\end{scope}  % ---------- after this scope

\begin{scope}[scale=0.8,transform shape,align=center,white,fill opacity=1]
% little circles inside
\draw[style=shade, top color=white, bottom color=forestgreen][black](0.25,-1.45)circle(1.50cm) 
 node[text width=2.25cm,text=white] {\textsc{Market-Cap\\ Weighted}};
\draw[style=shade, top color=white, bottom color=SchoolColor][black](6,-1.45)circle(1.50cm) 
 node[text width=2.25cm,text=white] {\textsc{Actively\\ Managed}};
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
%\end{figure}
\end{document}
```