# how to create such pictures and text inside them

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, pspicture

Could anyone help me, I need exactly this [image]

Comment: Almost a duplicate : http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/349784/116936

Comment: ... and, for the symbols, you may use 
`\mathcal{W}^\ast`, etc. with `\usepackage{amssymb}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.